# \path{} command and blank spaces

Tags: paths

The document that I am writing includes lots of paths to files. Many of them have blank spaces that I am powerless to remove since they originate outside of my domain of control. But the `\path{}` command that this document uses actually butchers those paths by removing blank spaces. `\path{C:\My Documents} outputs` MyDocuments`. I am not sure who thought that it was a good idea or even acceptable to alter the command's argument.

I cannot simply switch to `\texttt{}` because this would require escaping lots of backslashes, underscores, dollar signs, etc, all over the document.

How can I fix the result of the `\path{}` command?

Comment: It is very hard to answer this because you do not post *any* code. The only `\path` command I know is in Ti*k*Z, obviously you are not referring to this one.

Comment: What package defines the `\path` command? I don't think it's part of standard `LaTeX`.

Comment: \usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url} %before hyperref if hyperref is used
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\path{C:\My Documents}

\end{document}
```

[image]